# How to display capture image from camera and display in imageview from file path?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

My problem after taking a photo and then createImageFile .. onActivityResult, photo does not appear on img_photo. how to make appear in img_photo ?

```
 img_photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);
        // take a photo from camera
        imgBtnCamera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnCamera);
        imgBtnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                    }

                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PhotoSubmitActivity.this,
                                "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

**Create image file**

```
// Create image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

**onActivityResult**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            try {
                Log.v("This is totally working", "Yeah!");
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
                img_photo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                img_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

I attended training on this link [Taking Photos Simply](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskCaptureIntent)

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem too.but i solved it.
@Driyanto Saputro see in my code where i placed a comment for save Captured image in ImageView.
also Note : i am working on Custom Camera not Using Existing Camera.
i paste my code below to Save Captured image in imageView.

```
public void CaptureImage() {
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        private File imageFile;

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            try {
                // Convert byte array into bitmap
                final Bitmap originalBitmap = MainActivity.decodeSampledBitmapFromByte(getApplicationContext(), data);

                // Rotate Image
                Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
                final Bitmap rotatedBitmap;
                if (mCameraId == CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    rotateMatrix.postRotate(270);
                } else {
                    rotateMatrix.postRotate(90);
                }

                rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, originalBitmap.getWidth(), originalBitmap.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);

                final File imageFolder;
                if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                    imageFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CameraApp/Images");
                } else {
                    imageFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CameraApp/Images");
                }

                boolean success = true;
                if (!imageFolder.exists()) {
                    success = imageFolder.mkdirs();
                }
                if (success) {
                    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                    imageFile = new File(imageFolder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + getFileNameCustomFormat() + " " + "Image.jpg");

                    SavedImagePath = getFileNameCustomFormat() + " " + "Image.jpg";
                    // imageFile.createNewFile();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image Not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                // Save image into gallery
                if (rotatedBitmap != null) {
                    rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outputStream);
                }

                FileOutputStream file_out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                file_out.write(outputStream.toByteArray());
                file_out.close();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo Captured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Code For Captured Image Save in a ImageView.
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String imagePath = imageFolder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + SavedImagePath;
                        Uri myURI = Uri.parse(imagePath);
                        imgBtnThumbnail.setImageURI(myURI);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo Saved on ImageView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I hope it will help You.(:

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will help

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    // directory name to store captured images and videos
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

    private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

    private ImageView imgPreview;
    private VideoView videoPreview;
    private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
        btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
        btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);

        /**
         * Capture image button click event
         */
        btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // capture picture
                captureImage();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Record video button click event
         */
        btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // record video
                recordVideo();
            }
        });

        // Checking camera availability
        if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // will close the app if the device does't have camera
            finish();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checking device has camera hardware or not
     * */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
     */
    private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }

    /**
     * Recording video
     */
    private void recordVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

        // set video quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                                                            // name

        // start the video capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // successfully captured the image
                // display it in image view
                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // video successfully recorded
                // preview the recorded video
                previewVideo();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display image from a path to ImageView
     */
    private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {
            // hide video preview
            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                    options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Previewing recorded video
     */
    private void previewVideo() {
        try {
            // hide image preview
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            videoPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());
            // start playing
            videoPreview.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * ------------ Helper Methods ---------------------- 
     * */

    /**
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /**
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/

Comment: I got this error : getOutputMediaFileUri(PhotoSubmitActivity.java:252),
captureImage(PhotoSubmitActivity.java:175),
access$000(PhotoSubmitActivity.java:41),
onClick(PhotoSubmitActivity.java:105)